# How to find sum of given string which is already having + operater through which it is jointed

Tags: java

My name is Nitin Nagpal.

I am having a query which was given to me by my friend as a challenge to which I was not able to solve till yet even after expiration of given time period.

static int expression("10+20+20+20")

He want sum of this string ("10+20+20+20") = 70

without using default functions available in Java. We have to put logic only to solve this

example.

Comment: [Shunting-yard Algorithm](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) developed by Dijkstra would work just fine for this example.

Comment: By default functions you mean no use of loop,string methods etc?